# Trigonometry absolute value

Tags: trigonometry

> Does absolute value for $\csc(x)$ and for $\operatorname{sec}(x)$ exists in graphs?
>
> $y=|\csc(x)|$ and $y=|\operatorname{sec}(x)|$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Why do you think it shouldn't exist?

Comment: "exist in graphs": what do you mean ???

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you may graph and evaluate $ y=\lvert\csc(x)\rvert$ and $ y=\lvert\sec(x)\rvert$.

You will see many vertical asymptotes at the points were the function is not defined due to dividing by zero.

These vertical asymptotes for $ y=\lvert\csc(x)\rvert$ are at multiples of $\pi$ where $y=\sin(x)$ has its zeros.

Similarly for $y=\lvert\sec(x)\rvert$ you have vertical asymptotes where $y=\cos(x)$ has its zeros.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Does that mean that sin(x) is |sin(x)| if |csc(x)| ? I mean all the curve are positives for sin(x) and csc(x) then?

Comment: Yes when you take absolute value of a function it is positive .